# edit form not working with mysql in PHP, processes data to href but doesn't run test print line

Tags: php, mysql, post, get

after trying to debug this snipet of code for hours, I find I cannot figure out why my edit form wont update for the life of me. I'm not sure if it's because I'm not using GET or POST methods correctly, I'm mis-using mysql, or a combination of the both. I cant even figure out why a line of print "hi"; wont show up. if i take out the line of code testing when the edit submit button is hit the print lines come out but my database wont update. So I figure I'm stuck where I can't do anymore print line debugging untill I figure out what I'm doing wrong. here is my code.. I commented next to the "print "hi";" line that doesnt show up. keep in mind I'm pretty sure I tried every combination of GET and POST and it still doesnt show up...

```
<html lang="en">

<head>  
    <title>Employee</title>
</head>
<body>

<a href="employ.php">Clean</a> <br>

<form method="post" action="employ.php">
<input type="text" name="fname">First Name<br>
<input type="text" name="lname">Last Name<br>
<input type="text" name="email">email<br>
<input type="text" name="zip">zip code<br>

<input type="submit" name="add" value="Add"> <!-- button itself -->
</form>
<br>


<?php                   //server    login name    password  database
$link = mysqli_connect("server", "login", "password", "database") or die(mysqli_error());




if(isset($_POST['add'])) //this processes after user submits data.
{
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $zip = $_POST['zip'];

    $re = "/^[a-zA-Z]+(([\'\- ][a-zA-Z])?[a-zA-Z]*)*$/";
    $reEmail = "/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+$/";
    $reZip = "/^\d{5}$/";

    //if user passes re test
    if( preg_match($re, $fname) && preg_match($re, $lname) 
        && preg_match($reEmail, $email) && preg_match($reZip, $zip) )
    {   //display current table
        $querycheck = "select * from employees where fname='$fname' and email='$email'";
        $resultcheck = mysqli_query($link, $querycheck); //link query to database

        if(mysqli_num_rows($resultcheck) == 0)// test if query does "nothing"
        {//if not process the insert query
            $query = "insert into employees values('', '$fname', '$lname', '$email', '$zip')";
            mysqli_query($link, $query); //link query to database
            print "Employee Added"; // print confirmation
        }
        else
        {
            print "That record already exists!";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        print "You did not fill out the form correctly!";
    }

} ////////////////////////////////edit portion/////////////////////////////
if(isset($_GET['edit']))
{
    print "teseting edit<br><br>";
    ?>

    <form method="get" action="employ.php"> 
    <input type="text" name="fname" value = "<?php echo $_GET['fname']?>">First Name<br>
    <input type="text" name="lname" value = "<?php echo $_GET['lname']?>">Last Name<br>
    <input type="text" name="email" value = "<?php echo $_GET['email']?>">email<br>
    <input type="text" name="zip"   value = "<?php echo $_GET['zip']?>">zip code<br>

    <input type="hidden" name="employeeid" value = "<?php echo $_GET['employeeid']?>">

    <input type="submit" name="endedit" value="Edit"> <!-- button itself -->
    </form>

    <?php

    print "teseting end edit <br><br>";



    if(isset($_POST['endedit'])) //this processes after user submits edited data
    {                                //tried get and post
        print "hi";  // DOESNT APPEAR
        $fname = $_POST['fname'];
        $lname = $_POST['lname'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $zip = $_POST['zip'];
        $employeeidtemp = $_POST['employeeid'];

        $re = "/^[a-zA-Z]+(([\'\- ][a-zA-Z])?[a-zA-Z]*)*$/";
        $reEmail = "/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+$/";
        $reZip = "/^\d{5}$/";

        //if user passes re test
        if( preg_match($re, $fname) && preg_match($re, $lname) 
        && preg_match($reEmail, $email) && preg_match($reZip, $zip) )
        {   //display current table
            //$querycheck = "select * from employees where employeeid='$employeeidtemp'";
            //$resultcheck = mysqli_query($link, $querycheck); //link query to database

        //  if(mysqli_num_rows($resultcheck) == 0)// test if query does "nothing"
        //  {
                $query = "UPDATE employees SET fname='$fname', lname='$lname', email='$email', zip='$zip' WHERE employeeid='$employeeidtemp'";
                mysqli_query($link, $query); //link query to database
                print "Employee Updated"; // print confirmation
        //  }
        //  else
        //      print "huh?";

        }
        else
        {
            print "You did not fill out the form correctly!";
        }

    }




}

if(isset($_GET['delete']))
{
    print "teseting delete<br><br>";
}



showemp();




function showemp()
{
    global $link;
    if(isset($_GET['choice']))
    {
        $choice = $_GET['choice'];
    }
    else
    {
        $choice = "lname";
    }

    $query = "select * from employees order by $choice";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);


// print table (happens first before input)

    // first print row of links/headers that sort
    print "<table border='1'>

    <tr>
    <th>Edit</th>
    <th>Delete</th>
    <th><a href='employ.php?choice=fname'>FNAME</a></th> 
    <th><a href='employ.php?choice=lname'>LNAME</a></th>
    <th><a href='employ.php?choice=email'>EMAIL</a></th>
    <th><a href='employ.php?choice=zip'>ZIP</a></th>
    </tr>";

    //while the next row (set by query) exists?
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
    {
        list($employeeid, $fname, $lname, $email, $zip) = $row;
        print "<tr>
        <td><a href='employ.php?edit=yes&employeeid=$employeeid&fname=$fname&lname=$lname&email=$email&zip=$zip'>Edit</a></td>
        <td><a href='employ.php?delete=yes&employeeid=$employeeid
                      onclick='return confirm(\"Are you sure\")'>Delete</a></td>
        <td>$fname</td>
        <td>$lname</td>
        <td>$email</td>
        <td>$zip</td>
        </tr>";
    }

    print "</table>";
}




?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The second form uses `method="get"`, so you should be using `$_GET` to read its inputs, not `$_POST`.

Comment: Where do you get the input for $_GET['edit'] from...??

Comment: @tramp he is getting from the submit value.

Comment: @Barmar I just tried replacing all the posts under it with get. didnt do anything... the print "hi"; still wont print

Comment: You have the test for `$_POST['endedit']` inside the block that runs when `$_GET['edit']` is set. They won't both be set on the same call.

Comment: `$_GET['edit']` is only set when the user clicks on the `Edit` link, not when they submit the form.

Comment: @EternalHour: Which submit...??

Comment: `<input type="submit" name="endedit" value="Edit">` for the second form.

Comment: @Barmar $_POST['endedit'] is inside the block that runs when $_GET['edit'] is set. $_GET['edit'] is activated when the user clicks the link "edit", then a form is shown which takes old record from the link and puts it in the form for editing, and then the $_POST['endedit'] is made available, once it is clicked then the test for wether is set is made.

Comment: But those are two separate invocations of the script. When the user clicks the link, `edit` is set. Then when he submits the form, `endedit` is set. But they're not BOTH set on the same call.

Comment: @EternalHour: I guess... He is getting it from one of the links...

Comment: @Barmar interesting! I took the endedit test out of the if and put it right after it, and it edited properly :D I didn't realize clicking a form button would instantaneously shut the whole block of code down.

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors:

1. You do not check the result of queries, use at least 
   **code mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));**

When I kick your code with checking errors, I found that adding query does not work - your empty string value for **employeeid** does not accepted for my integer field.

2. Do not use GET in forms. Always POST. If you need reaction on GET-url, write it separately or use $_REQUEST var.
3. In INSERT query always write fields. When you will decide to change list of fields in mysql table, then you can get the strange behavior of this code.
4. Your main error is that your condition with print 'hi' is inside the condition **if(isset($_GET['edit']))**, it does not work when user sublim form.

Comment: how can I transform the employeeid variable I get from the url to an int like its listed in my database?